# how to handle or debug run time threading exception

Tags: runtimeexception

I am getting the following exception:

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: XNIO007007: Thread is 
terminating
at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.execute(WorkerThread.java:568)
at org.xnio.AbstractIoFuture.runNotifier(AbstractIoFuture.java:354)
at org.xnio.AbstractIoFuture.runAllNotifiers(AbstractIoFuture.java:233)
at org.xnio.AbstractIoFuture.setCancelled(AbstractIoFuture.java:291)
at org.xnio.FutureResult.setCancelled(FutureResult.java:98)
at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread$ConnectHandle.forceTermination(WorkerThread.java:339)
at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:490.
```

In my app there are 3 threads running, one is the **main** thread and other two are **tcp server** thread and **tcp client** thread. After running the app for a long time it throws the above exception. I don't know which thread throwed this exception neither how to debug it.

Comment: The best way is to have a log file. So you know which trhead did what in which order.

Comment: how to solve this issue?

Comment: why is thread terminating?

Comment: How do you want me to know that ? Do you have a debug file ? Can you show the code that produced this error ?